# CMD Open 2 programs then close of 1st kill the other

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have two exe file I need run at the same time, and when the first get closed close the other one.

```
start programA.exe
start programB.exe

onclose(programA.exe)
taskkill /im programB.exe
```

Not working. Just for easier understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start notepad.exe
start /wait calc.exe
echo wait until calc.exe is finished
echo then kill notepad.exe
taskkill notepad.exe
```

Attention: if more than one instance of (in this example) Notepad is running, this may close the wrong one.